# Avalondock MVVM - Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visibility, avalondock

again I have problably a simple problem:

I'm trying to build a very simple MVVM - Application:

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <ad:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ad:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=Networks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           ActiveContent="{Binding Path=Active, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="300">
            <ad:LayoutRoot>
                <ad:LayoutPanel>
                    <ad:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                </ad:LayoutPanel>
            </ad:LayoutRoot>
            <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
            <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ad:LayoutItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        </ad:DockingManager>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Networks, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Active, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

For this example here I simplyfied it a bit.

Here is my ViewModel and my Model (I know not totally correct but i wanted to keep it short.)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {

                DataContext = this;
                InitializeComponent();

                Networks.Add(new DocumentVM("Title", "Text"));
                Networks.Add(new DocumentVM("Title2", "Text2"));
                Networks.Add(new DocumentVM("Title3", "Text3"));
            }


            private const string NetworksPropertyName = "Networks";
            private ObservableCollection<DocumentVM> _Networks = new ObservableCollection<DocumentVM>();
            public ObservableCollection<DocumentVM> Networks
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Networks;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Networks = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(NetworksPropertyName);
                }
            }

            private const string ActivePropertyName = "Active";
            private DocumentVM _Active;
            public DocumentVM Active
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Active;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Active = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(ActivePropertyName);
                }
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }

        }
```

**Model**

```
public class DocumentVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public DocumentVM(string Title, string Text)
            {
                this.Title = Title;
                this.Text = Text;
            }

            private const string IsVisiblePropertyName = "IsVisible";
            private bool _IsVisible;
            public bool IsVisible
            {
                get
                {
                    return _IsVisible;
                }
                set
                {
                    _IsVisible = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(IsVisiblePropertyName);
                }
            }

            private const string TitlePropertyName = "Title";
            private string _Title;
            public string Title
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Title;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Title = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(TitlePropertyName);
                }
            }

            private const string TextPropertyName = "Text";
            private string _Text;
            public string Text
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Text;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Text = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(TextPropertyName);
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to set my Documents Visible or Hide them via the Checkbox but the IsVisible Property does not get updated.

Thank you!!

EDIT:

I found out that if I use:

```
<ad:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=Networks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   AnchorablesSource="{Binding Path=Networks, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   ActiveContent="{Binding Path=Active, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="300">
```

The hiding of the AnchorablesItems work.
Is it possible that I cannot hide Documents? :(